# Search for a keyword and copy the whole line to a new file using perl

Tags: perl, search, automation

How can I recurse into multiple directories (in windows) and search for all the strings which starts from a particular name. (ex : all strings starting from "perl_") and copy the whole line to a new file.

Thanks for any pointers (existing websites?)

Comment: When you say `search for all the strings which starts`, did you actually mean to say `search the directories for file names which starts` OR did you mean `search the files in each directory for strings which starts`?

Comment: @TLP I puzzled over that question too.  Finally I decided that he must mean to look at lines of each file, since he said, "copy the whole line to a new file."  However, a very similar question showed up on PerlMonks within the same hour as this one, and that question was looking for all filenames in a recursive directory search. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=974650  Clearly not the same question, but it's rare that two "File::Find" types of questions would turn up within minutes of each other on two different Perl-related forums.  Two different approaches to the same homework assignment?:)

Comment: @DavidO I always think it does not bode well for a programmer to express himself so ambiguously.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind), from the core Perl distribution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $starting_path = '/path/to/begin/searching';

open my $output, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

find(
    sub {
        return unless -e -f;
        if ( open my $infile, '<', $_ ) {
            while ( my $line = <$infile> ) {
                print $output $line if $line =~ m/^perl_/;
            }
        }
        else {
            warn "$_ couldn't be opened: $!";
        }
    },
    $starting_path
);

close $output or die $!;
```

If you need additional help on crafting the search pattern, see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) from Perl's POD (Perl's documentation), included with every distribution.

Answer (score -1):

For the string matching, if Perl uses the same regular expression as ruby, I believe it does, then you can use http://rubular.com/ to test regular expressions. To match regular expressions in Perl you do this

```
if $string =~ /regular expression/
```

The regular expression below should match perl_ at the beging of a string

```
/^perl_/
```

To help yourself just Google "regular expressions Perl" or "regex Perl" and you will find a few useful websites explaining how to use regular expressions in Perl.

For traversing through multiply directories, see chapter 2: *Filesystems* in [Automating System Administration with Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006396).

I hope this answers all your questions.